# Get bits from byte and slice 2 bit pairs

Tags: c++, c++11, bit-manipulation, byte, bit

I am new to C++. In Python 3 I can convert the string 'ABC' into selected bits like this and print, whenever a pair of bits are 11:

```
s = 'ABC'
for i, char in enumerate(s):
    for j in range(4):
        if ord(char) >> 2*j & 0b11 == 3:
            print(i, char, ord(char), j, ord(char) >> 2*j & 0b11)
```

Which returns:

```
2 C 67 0 3
```

How do I do the same in C++; i.e. how do I identify bits 1 and 2 of the character 'C' being 11? I currently have this code:

```
//#include <string>
//#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
//using namespace std;
int main(){
  const int bits_in_byte = 8;
  std::string s = "ABC";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
      std::cout << i << ' ' << s[i] << ' ' << std::bitset<bits_in_byte>(s[i]) << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
0 A 01000001
0 A 01000001
0 A 01000001
0 A 01000001
1 B 01000010
1 B 01000010
1 B 01000010
1 B 01000010
2 C 01000011
2 C 01000011
2 C 01000011
2 C 01000011
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same bit manipulation trick that you used in Python:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
        if (((s[i] >> (2*j)) & 3) == 3) {
            std::cout << i << " " << s[i] << " " << (int)s[i] << " " << j << " " << ((s[i] >> 2*j) & 3) << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

You do not need to use `ord`, because character types of C++ are among the integral types, and are, therefore, freely convertible to integers.

Note the use of parentheses to force the expected order of evaluation.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/NE7Wxl)

Comment: Thanks! You are right that I get `warning: & has lower precedence than ==; == will be evaluated first [-Wparentheses]`, when doing `if ((s[i] >> (2*j)) & 3 == 3) {` as in your original answer instead of `if (((s[i] >> (2*j)) & 3) == 3) {` as in your edited answer. This shifts `s[i] >> (2*j)` and then `& 3` masks. I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To check the nth bit is set or not you can use something like below

`bit at position x of M = (M & 1<<x) //0 if its zero 1 if its one`